# Memory Warning when calling Main Queue in didOutputSampleBuffer

Tags: xcode, memory-management, ios6, avfoundation, grand-central-dispatch

I am getting memory warnings when I try to update the UI on the main queue from:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

The delegate method is called on a separate, serial queue in GCD, so when I want to update the UI from frames I analyzed in the above method, I call:

```
long wait = dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.myUISemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
if(wait == 0)
{
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.myUISemaphore);
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    self.numberFinderMarksLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.data];
    });
}
```

As you can see, I attempted to use semaphores to no avail. I tried locking the thread and unlocking after the call to the UI but that didn't work either. Nothing stops those memory warnings. After five or so, the whole things crashes silently.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap everything inside of your delegate method with:

```
@autoreleasepool {

}
```

That fixed it for me. You probably have some CGImageRefs or something you aren't freeing. (Which must be done manually, even in ARC)